# How do I get the string value of a JSON value without quotes ("")?

Tags: json, rust

I have this code:

```
let data = r#"
{
"name": "john",
"address": "street 34",
"age": 22,
"phones": [
"+34 21213232367",
"+34 82837826476"
]
}
"#;

let value1: Value = serde_json::from_str::<Value>(data)?;
println!("name {} ", value1["name"]);
```

This prints =>

```
name "john"
```

However, I'd like to print

```
name john
```

Without "", how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`JsonValue::as_str`](https://docs.rs/json/latest/json/enum.JsonValue.html#method.as_str) method (if you are sure that the value is a `str`):

```rust
println!("name {} ", value1["name"].as_str().expect("Value is a str"));
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba6ea85739e930edb854af4ddec09628)

Answer (score 1):

Serde JSON is not mean to be used with `Value`. Prefer declaring a struct that represents your JSON object, like this:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Contact {
    name: String,
    address: String,
    age: u8,
    phones: Vec<String>,
}

// or non Owned version but prefer owned version
// unless you know what you are doing
// #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
// struct Contact<'a> {
//     name: &'a str,
//     address: &'a str,
//     age: u8,
//     phones: Vec<&'a str>,
// }

fn main() {
    let data = r#"
{
    "name": "john",
    "address": "street 34",
    "age": 22,
    "phones": [
        "+34 21213232367",
        "+34 82837826476"
    ]
}
"#;

    let john: Contact = serde_json::from_str(data).unwrap();
    println!("name {} ", john.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```rust
if let Some(Value::String(string)) = value1["name"] {
  println!("{}", string);
}
```

Comment: this would not work, it should be `value["name"]`

Comment: (edited to fix @Netwaves comment)